# Problem about value assignment in Arrayfire

Tags: c++, flashlight, arrayfire

I'm using Arrayfire and Flashlight evaluating a network.

```cpp
auto tmp = output(af::seq(2, 10), af::span, af::span, af::span);
auto softmax_tmp = fl::softmax(tmp, 0);
output(af::seq(2,10),af::span,af::span,af::span)=softmax_tmp;
```

`output` is a tensor with the shape of (12,100,1,1). Now I want to pull out the (2,10) dims of the tensor and for the extracted 100 9-dim vectors, apply softmax operation to them. Then put them back. Codes above.

Problem is that the 3rd line doesn't work. `softmax_tmp` is the right value, but the assignment operator in the 3rd line just failed. Exactly it can pass the compilation successfully, but `output` remains the old value as in 1st line.

Who could help me? A lot thanks really.

Comment: You are reading from 2-10 but writing to 2-27. The sizes are different here aren't they?

Comment: Ah thanks, it's typo

Comment: I implemented this using just ArrayFire and everything looked fine in v3.6.4